# Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку формы 2, кнопка с таким же номером выделялась на форме 1

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 2 формы в них по 3 кнопки.

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на одну из кнопки формы 1 выделялась кнопка этого же номера на форме 2 (т.е. если нажата первая - то выделяется первая на форме 2).

И также наоборот. с формы 2 на форму 1.

Формы не модальные. В первой форме 3 кнопки в toolstrip, во второй - 3 radioButton в groupBox.

Comment: Меня интересует лишь то, как выделить кнопку, чтобы при нажатии другой, например кнопки 2, кнопка 1 перестала выделяться.

Comment: А как вы свои кнопки нумеруете? Для данной кнопки как определить ее номер?

Comment: Не думаю, что это сильно важно. Просто по порядку например. Номера кнопок просто для удобства

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вот. Накидал по быстрому

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form.UpdateRadioButtons(0);
    }

    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form.UpdateRadioButtons(1);
    }

    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form.UpdateRadioButtons(2);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private RadioButton[] _radioButtons;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _radioButtons = new RadioButton [3] { radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3 };
    }

    public void UpdateRadioButtons(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _radioButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            _radioButtons[index].Checked = false;
        }
        _radioButtons[index].Checked = true;

    }
}
```